# Combine two content encodings sections in a single page

Tags: html, content-encoding

I developed a web application that allows users to modify existing web pages.
When a user type a url of an existing web page, I read the content of this page and using an ajax call, i display the content in a div inside my web application.
Now my problem is that often the content encoding of the existing web page is different than my web app (I use utf-8)
Is there a way to load content using an ajax call with different content encoding than the one of the main page?
Thanks,
Amir

Comment: Unfortunately not since I have deep client side integration between the content of the external site and my own framework. any other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Your only option is an `iframe` (as alex said). Encoding is a meta data that is unique for each html document.

If you need 2 different encodings on your page you will need 2 different html documents.

Comment: Thanks Rui and Alex.
Since I can't use an iFrame, I guess my only option is to use UTF-8 for my main app and convert the other content to UTF-8 on the server side. Does anyone know how to do it?
Thanks,
Amir

Answer (score 0):

Use an `iframe`.

```
<iframe src="http://www.example.com" id="second-site"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometime ago i used this script to convert my LaTeX files from ISO to UTF-8:

```
#!/bin/sh

FILES=*.tex

for f in $FILES; do
    iconv --to-code=ISO-8859-1 --from-code=UTF-8 $f > iso/$f
done
```

**Note:** *this answer is a reply to AmirGl comment.*